# Access URL in promise each

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using Bluebird.js and request-promise NPM module.
**I want to access promise URL or item.transactionID as in the code below.**
I try to find many things but failed to work
How can we achieve this.

```
    paymentIDArray.forEach(item => {
        let p = rp({
            uri: API + item.transactionID,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic " + authCode
            },
            simple: false,
            resolveWithFullResponse: false,
            transform2xxOnly: false
        }).promise();
        promises.push(p);
    });

    await Promise
        .all(promises)
        .each(async (inspection) => {
            if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {

               // I want item.transactionID of each promise here

                let result = JSON.parse(inspection.value());

            } else {
                logger.error(inspection);
                logger.error("A promise in the array was rejected with", inspection.reason());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `item.id` to the promise value you push

```
paymentIDArray.forEach(item => {
    let p = rp({
        uri: API + item.transactionID,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + authCode
        },
        simple: false,
        resolveWithFullResponse: false,
        transform2xxOnly: false
    }).promise();
    promises.push(p.then(inspection => ({inspection, id: item.id})));
});

// each promise, instead of being just the result of `rp` is now {inspection: result of rp, id: item.id}
await Promise
.all(promises)
//    vvvvv do you really need async? you are not awaiting in this code
.each(async ({inspection, id}) => {
    if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {

        // id is the required item.id

        let result = JSON.parse(inspection.value());

    } else {
        logger.error(inspection);
        logger.error("A promise in the array was rejected with", inspection.reason());
    }
});
```